# If there are 20 nodes in network and all are receiving transaction and after 10 min

Tags: majority-attack

Question 1) If there are 20 nodes in network and all are receiving transaction and after 10 min all will pick transaction from their transaction pool and start creating block, now will all nodes will use same transactions to create block or each node can have different transaction in that particular block

Question 2) If there are 20 nodes in network and all starts creating block, what will happen if more then one node will create the block at same time

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, each node (assuming that it is a miner) can pick a different set of transactions.
2. Eventually one block will get more work built on top of it than all the others and the other competing blocks at the same height in the chain will become stale and be discontinued. Effectively the blockchain forks but eventually one branch survives and the others die. Ultimately only one node gets a usable mining reward & fees.